# Can't get data by using getElementsByTagName

Tags: javascript, dom, mfc, xml-parsing, google-maps-api-2

Thank you for reading my problem. I using Google Map API to parse XML. The XML data is produced by MFC and then I send it to the HTML,`<input type="hidden" name="XMLData" id="XMLfromMFC" value="" />.`

Then I use JavaScript to parse this XML string and do some work,but when I click a button which will parse the XML string, an error occured "can't get data from getElementsByTagName:it's null or undefined.

But the JS code is the [example code of Google Map API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/v2/services?hl=en), so I have no idea how to solve this problem. Please help me!

Additinal information:I use WebBrowser in MFC to load a HTML page which all code in. GXml is a namespace of Google Map API and it has that method. I guess if MFC WebBrowser isn't support the getElementsByTagName() method ? If so, how to solve it?

```
function loadXMLData()
{
    var strXML = document.getElementById('XMLfromMFC');
    var xmlDoc = GXml.parse(strXML);

    var polylines = xmlDoc.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("road");

    for (var i = 0; i < polylines.length; i++) {
         addPolylines(polylines[i]);
      }
}

function addPolylines(node)
{
   var points = node.getElementsByTagName("point");
   var pts = [];

   for (var i = 0; i < points.length; i++)
   {
   pts[i] = new      GLatLng(parseFloat(points[i].getAttribute("lat")),parseFloat(points[i].getAttribute("lon")));
   }
           for (var i = 0; i < points.length; i++) {
               pts[i] = new GLatLng(parseFloat(points[i].getAttribute("lat")), parseFloat(points[i].getAttribute("lon")));
           }   

           var polyline = new GPolyline(pts);
           map.addOverlay(polyline);
           return polyline;
       }
```

The XML data is like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<AllRoadsData>
<road>
<id>1</id>
<roadName>first</roadName>
<roadWidth>2</roadWidth>
<pointsNum>9</pointsNum>
<maxSpeed>80</maxSpeed>
<point lon="42.361081" lat="-71.070213"/>
<point lon="42.361128" lat="-71.068625"/>
<point lon="42.361192" lat="-71.066844"/>
</road>
<road>
<id>2</id>
<roadName>second</roadName>
<roadWidth>4</roadWidth>
<pointsNum>5</pointsNum>
<maxSpeed>30</maxSpeed>
<point lon="42.357291" lat="-71.065063"/>
<point lon="42.358290" lat="-71.065085"/>
</road>
</AllRoadsData>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using the deprecated Google Maps API v2, which is not recommended for new development, and could stop working as early as May 2013.  You should move to the v3 API (which doesn't include any of this functionality).

You should look at your javascript errors, I suspect that xmlDoc.documentElement is null.

Comment: thank you, yes,you are right,MFC error report is getElementsByTagName() is null, so I think xmlDoc didn't get DOM successfully. As to the API version, because I don't know how to use V3 version API,so I have to use V2 right now. I use Firebug to load this page and directly give the value string. But it still didn't work and has no wrong! I don't know why, please help me.......

Comment: Have you verified your xml is valid?  It isn't worth my time to support v2; you should figure out how to use v3 now rather than later.  For using v2, the best reference is [Mike Williams' tutorial](http://econym.org.uk/gmap/). Or you could look at http://www.geocodezip.com, there are lots of examples of both v2 and v3 there.